# git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote [URL repo]

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

i want to clone project by source tree
but error
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote [URL REPO]
Output:
Error: fatal: unable to access [URL REPO] : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Command: hg identify extensions.hgext.hgsubversion=! [URL REPO]
Output:
Error: (the full certificate chain may not be available locally; see "hg help debugssl")
abort: error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)

Command: perl.exe C:\Users\banna\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-3.4.3\tools\svn.pl info [URL REPO]
Output:
Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified